# How to make a triangle hover effect behind menu option

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a hover effect for a menu -
It should be pretty simple but I haven't found any scss or css work arounds yet... Below is an image that shows specifically what I'm talking about.

[image: Image Link]

Comment: I might try this one later, but in the meantime it'd be nice if you'd add what you've tried so far.
Also, SCSS is not the same as LESS so you might want to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `linear-gradient` will do it:

```css
.container {
 background:grey;
 padding:10px;
 }
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, red 51%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">TEXT</div>
  <div class="nav">long TEXT</div>
  <div class="nav">A</div>
  <div class="nav">BBBBBBBBBBB</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use clip-path to shape the triangle, although [browser support Eh.](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

```css
button {
  background: #112b1bb8;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<button>Brand</button>
<button>Link Link</button>
<button>O</button>
```